# How to get VBA code to run on Multiple Sheets?

Tags: vba, excel

I was wondering how to get this code to work on every sheet and new sheets that will be made in the Excel workbook. The new sheet Thank you to everyone that helps.

```
  Dim cmt As Comment
  Dim charCount As String
  Dim prevTarget As Range
  Sub Worksheet_C(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Target.Value <> Empty Or Target.Value <> "0" Then
            If Target.Value <> Empty Then
            Set prevTarget = Target
            Set Target = Target
            End If
        Set cmt = prevTarget.Comment
            If Target = Empty Then
            Set prevTarget = Target
            End If
            If cmt Is Nothing Then
            'MsgBox "There is no comment"
            ElseIf Len(cmt.Text) > 150 Then
            charCount = Len(cmt.Text)
            MsgBox "Character Limit is 150. Your comment contains " + charCount + "."
            End If
    End If
End Sub
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
Call Worksheet_C(Target)
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The **`Workbook_SheetSelectionChange()`** in `ThisWorkbook` witll execute for all sheets:

---

In **ThisWorkbook** module:

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Workbook_SheetSelectionChange(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As Range)
    RestrictCommentSize Target
End Sub
```

---

**Module1** (a new generic VBA module) can contain your initial Sub `Worksheet_C` (cleaned up a bit)

---

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub RestrictCommentSize(ByVal Target As Range)
    With Target
        If .CountLarge = 1 Then
            If Len(.Value2) <> 0 And .Value2 <> "0" And Not .Comment Is Nothing Then
                If Len(.Comment.Text) > 150 Then
                    Dim msg As String
                    msg = "Your comment contains " & Len(.Comment.Text) & " characters"
                    MsgBox msg & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & "(more than the max of 150)"
                End If
            End If
        End If
    End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

*Worksheet_SelectionChange* is a worksheet specific routine.

If new sheets are created manually, you cannot easily control the sheet's VBA content (unless you run a background process to poll the sheets and check if the code exists).

However, if the sheets are created by code, you can add code that will also create the sheet specific VBA code.